# Return the size of array property after updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Description**

---

Trying to create a "like button" for blog posts; which stores the likes based on IP address.

This is a sample document in my collection called `blogs`:

```
{ _id:123123,
  title: "title here",
  desc: "some other text here",
  likes: [
   {ip: "10.0.0.1"},
   {ip: "0.1.1.1"},
  ]
}
```

After the user clicks the `like` button, the document gets updated using the code below:

```
 dbo.collection('blogs').findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id:ObjectId(id)},
            {$addToSet: {likes: {ip: uip}}},
            {}, // TODO: options
            function(err, res) {});
```

**Question**

---

- What should I pass in the `TODO` line in the code above, so that the function return the total number of `likes` in the document, after updating it? (for example: `{numOfLikes: 3}`)
- Is it possible to return the size of the array property of the updated document? in one database call?

**What I tried..**

---

I tried passing the following as the options (the `TODO` line):

```
{"projection":{ numOfLikes:{ $size: {"$ifNull" : ["$likes", []]}}} }
```

However, it throws an exception since `numOfLikes` is not a property of the document.

**Note**

---

I am using `mongodb` with `node.js`, using [the official mongodb driver for node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/, did you try the `returnNewDocument` option? You should be able to access the `likes` array from the return object of your function and get its new length. Something like:

```
dbo.collection('blogs').findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id:ObjectId(id)},
            {$addToSet: {likes: {ip: uip}}},
            {returnNewDocument: True},
            function(err, res) { console.log(res.likes.length) });
```

Comment: Since im using node js driver: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate I should set `returnOriginal: false`